# Detecting wrongful aliasing at compile or run time

Tags: compilation, fortran

Is there some tool (or compile flag) that can detect problematic aliasing in Fortran code either during compilation or at run time? I see gfortran has `-Waliasing`, but that only detects the most egregious case (e.g. `call whatever(x,x)`, but not `call whatever(x(1),x(1))`). Intel's ifort has `-fno-alias`, but apparently that just means the compiled code may give different results. Consider a code like this:

```
program main
implicit none
real :: x(100)
integer :: i

do i=1,size(x)
  x(i) = i
end do

call sub(100,x(1:100),x(1:100))

contains

subroutine sub(n,a,b)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n
real, intent(in) :: a(n)
real, intent(out) :: b(n)

b(:) = a(:)

end subroutine sub

end program main
```

I don't get any kind of warning (compiling or running), due to using the same memory addresses (`x(1:100)`) for both dummy arguments (`a` and `b`), where one of them is modified, which as far as I understand is forbidden by the standard.

Comment: I guess your issue is that it doesnt throw warnings that you supply `x(1)` as input and output variable? Or do I misunderstand your question and the actual issue is that the input arguments are of length 1 instead of 100 (as `size(x)` will yield)?

Comment: @Jack - it's the first case

Comment: @Jack Indeed the problem is the aliasing, not the sizes. I've modified the example slightly. (`x(1)` -> `x(1:100)`)

Comment: Don't know any but I would like to see what the NAG compiler does with this. Unfortunately I don't have access to it currently

Comment: @IanBush I don't have direct access to NAG, but in a larger program I got a crash with something like "Invalid operation". After some tweaking I could find out this was the problem, but it also disappeared if I removed the `intent`s, so I'd say this is more a case of different (unpredictable) results, rather than a true warning/diagnostic.

Comment: The code is wrong. Deleting the intents doesn't make it right - it is still invalid without them. Others can tell me if the compiler is required to diagnose this (I doubt it) but a high quality implementation will be able to. The NAG compiler is the best I know for this (though I'm biased as I used to work there)

Comment: @IanBush can find the answer (no) to whether aliasing violation is required to be diagnosed in F2018 15.5.2.13. In general such detection is what is known as "slightly tricky" so relying on detection of all faulty cases, without false reporting, is best avoided.

Comment: @IanBush, fwiw, compiling with `nagfor -C=all -f2008 main.f90` (with `NAG Fortran Compiler Release 6.1(Tozai) Build 6116`) results in no compile- or runtime messages on my system.

Comment: Don't explore too much further with NAG: "The -C=alias option will produce a runtime error when it is detected that assignment to a dummy argument affects another dummy argument. At this release this is only detected for scalar dummy arguments."

Comment: And for completeness: it isn't possible to do complete alias violation checking at "compile time". It is very easy to write a program where violation or conformance with aliasing restrictions depends on user input when running.

Comment: Agreed - but for complete completeness (and @francescalus I know you know this) it should be possible to include code at compile time to do appropriate runtime checking - c.f. the NAG compiler and uninitialized variables