# Why BLAS SAXPY updates input/output vector Y?

Tags: function, lapack, blas

What is the rationale for the SAXPY routine of the BLAS specification (http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_level_1) to perform the update (1): Y = A * X + Y, rather than the new assignment (2): Z = A * X + Y ?

To perform Z = A * X + Y using (1), we need to do (pseudo code):

```
Z = Y
SAXPY(A,X,Z)
```

For arrays of size N, that is 1 extra O(N) array assignment when compared to (2): that seems less efficient. On top of that (2) allows (1) if vector Y is passed for the output Z vector so it would seem both more general and more efficient.

I would be very interested in hearing about the principles supporting the design choice of (1) over that of (2) in most implementations I've come around, e.g. LAPACK. Thank you very much.

Comment: See comments to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65842064/10774817). Supposedly, according to F2018 15.5.2.13 it is invalid to have the same variable supplied for multiple dummy arguments. Thus, you could not rebuild `Y=A*X+Y` given a procedure that computes `Z=A*X+Y`. I will check the standard myself when I find time for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jack. I can definitely see how it could go wrong for operations such as matrix multiply. In the case of linear combinations of vectors however, it seems that the specification F2018 15.5.2.13 would not apply as the arguments are not overlapping, i.e. once I compute Y[0] = A*X[0]+Y[0], I don't need Y[0] anymore to compute y[1], ... y[N-1]